# Opening multiple Windows Explorer windows with screen snap

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, aero-snap

I am wondering if there is a way to use Windows Batch or some other medium to open multiple Windows Explorer windows with the screen snapping kind functionality you get when you are gripping an explorer window an you drag it over to the far right or left edge of a screen.

I'm trying to envision a way to get two side by side explorer windows (or maybe even four) on one screen quickly, instead of manually opening as many explorer windows as needed. This is only needed for a single monitor and it would be fine to define a fixed reference points (e.g. 0,0 and 1024,0) and even dimensions for these windows.

Would it be possible to make an exe that just opens these?

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not a direct solution, you might try the free QDir, http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/q-dir-portable, or similar Explorer replacement. QDir can open from one to *four* Explorer panes in one window, which can be maximized, if you wish.
QDir has the "look and feel" of Windows Explorer, so there is a negligible learning curve.
Similar software is FreeCommander, http://www.freecommander.com/.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't answering the question, but pressing the window key (the windows logo on your keyboard) and using the arrow keys gives you the screen snapping that you want.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that as well, but I'm looking for 2-4 unique explorer folders. They can be fixed locations, but they are not going to all be the same location. Point being, even with keyboard snapping the paths would have to be navigated.